# Start docker-compose automatically on EC2 startup

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have a linux AMI 2 AWS instance with some services orchestrated via docker-compose, and I am using docker-compose up or docker-compose start commands to start them all. Now I am in the process to start/stop my ec2 instance automatically every day, but once it is started, I want to run some ssh to be able to change to the directory where docker-compose.yml file is, and then start it.

something like:

```
#!
cd /mydirectory
docker-compose start
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using cron for this as it is easy. Most of the corn supports non-standard instructions like `@daily`, `@weekly`, `@monthly`, `@reboot`.

You can put this either in a shell script and schedule that in crontab as `@reboot /path/to/shell/script`
or
you can specify the docker-compose file using the absolute path and directly schedule it in crontab as `@reboot docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose.yml start`

#### Other possibilities:

1. Create a systemd service and enable it. All the enabled systems services will be started on powering.**(difficulty: medium)**
2. Put scripts under init.d and link it to rc*.d directory. These scripts are also started based on the priority.**(difficulty: medium)**

#### Bonus:

If you specify restart policy in the docker-compose file for a container it will autostart if you reboot or switch on the server. [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS) which can orchestrate docker containers and take care of your underlying OSes.

Answer (score 2):

Simply run the following command once on the host:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Afterwards the `restart: always` inside of your service in docker-compose.yml should start working.