# Launch docker automatically when starting ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, systemd

Everytime I restart my ec2 server I have to do:
`sudo systemctl start docker` and then `docker-compose up -d` to launch all my containers.
Would there be a way to automatically run these two commands at the start of the instance?
I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62341276/start-docker-compose-automatically-on-ec2-startup) and I think ideally I would like to know how to do that:

> Create a systemd service and enable it. All the enabled systems
> services will be started on powering.

Do you know how to create such systemd service?

**[EDIT 1]**: Following Chris William's comment, here is what I have done:

Thanks Chris, so I created a *docker_boot.service* with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=docker boot
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=ec2-user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I created it in `/etc/systemd/system` folder

I then did:

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl enable docker_boot
```

When I turn on the server, the only Docker images that are running are `certbot/certbot` and `telethonkids/shinyproxy`
Please find below the content of my `docker-compose.yml` file.
Do you see what is missing so that all images are up and running?

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  rstudio:
    environment:
      - USER=username
      - PASSWORD=password
    image: "rocker/tidyverse:latest"
    build:
     context: ./Docker_RStudio
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/home/maxence/R_and_Jupyter_scripts
    working_dir: /home/ec2-user/R_and_Jupyter_scripts
    container_name: rstudio
    ports:
      - 8787:8787

  jupyter:
    image: 'jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest'
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
     - /home/ec2-user/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/home/joyvan/R_and_Jupyter_scripts
    working_dir: /home/joyvan/R_and_Jupyter_scripts
    container_name: jupyter

  shiny:
    image: "rocker/shiny:latest"
    build:
     context: ./Docker_Shiny
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: shiny
    ports:
     - 3838:3838

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
     - net
    volumes:
     - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
     - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
     - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
     - 80:80
     - 443:443
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    depends_on:
     - shinyproxy

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
     - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
     - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"

  shinyproxy:
      image: telethonkids/shinyproxy
      container_name: shinyproxy
      restart: on-failure
      networks:
       - net
      volumes:
       - ./application.yml:/opt/shinyproxy/application.yml
       - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      expose:
        - 8080

  cron:
   build:
     context: ./cron
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
   container_name: cron
   volumes:
     - ./Docker_Shiny/app:/home
   networks:
     - net

networks:
 net:
   name: net
```

Comment: Is it Amazon Linux 2 instance?

Comment: yes Amazon Linux 2 AMI

Comment: Have you inspected logs, `docker-compose -f  docker-compose.yml logs`? Maybe they have some info on why it fails?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using **Amazon Linux 2** I tried to replicate the issue. Obviously, I don't have all the dependencies to run your exact `docker-compose.yml`, thus I used the `docker-compose.yml` from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) for my verification. The file setups `wordpress` with `mysql` .

Steps I took were following (executed as `ec2-user` in home folder):

#### 1. Install docker

```
sudo yum update -y  
sudo yum install -y docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

#### 2. Install docker-compose

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) -o /usr/bin/docker-compose

sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

#### 3. Create `docker-compose.yml`

```
mkdir myapp
```

Create file `./myapp/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

#### 4. Create `docker_boot.service`

The file is different then yours, as there were few potential issues in your file:

- not using absolute paths
- `ec2-user` may have no permissions to run docker

Create file `./myapp/docker_boot.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=docker boot
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/myapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f /home/ec2-user/myapp/docker-compose.yml up -d --remove-orphans

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### 5. Copy `docker_boot.service` to systemd

```
sudo cp -v ./myapp/docker_boot.service /etc/systemd/system
```

#### 6. Enable and start `docker_boot.service`

```
sudo systemctl enable docker_boot.service
sudo systemctl start docker_boot.service
```

Note: First `start` may take some time, as it will pull all docker images required. Alternatively start docker-compose manually first to avoid this.

#### 7. Check status of the `docker_boot.service`

```
sudo systemctl status docker_boot.service
```

#### 8. Check if the wordpress is up

```
curl -L localhost:8000
```

#### 9. Reboot

Check if the `docker_boot.service` is running after instance reboot by logging in into the instance and using `sudo systemctl status docker_boot.service` and/or `curl -L localhost:8000`.

Comment: Amazing Marcin! I have adapted it and it works like a charm! Would you know what lines I should add to do as well `docker-compose down` when turning off the instance? Thanks again!

Comment: @ML_Enthousiast No problem. Glad it worked out :-) I think you could try `ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f /home/ec2-user/myapp/docker-compose.yml down` in `[Service]`. But I haven't verified that, so I'm not certain.

Comment: You could just add "restart: always" in your docker-compose file. Then you won't need to create any docker_boot.service file. If the docker machine turns on the container will restart automatically.

Answer (score 5):

To have a service launch at launch you would run the following command `sudo systemctl enable docker`.

For having it then launch your `docker compose up -d` command you'd need to create a new service for your specific action, and then enable it with the contents similar to the below.

```
[Unit]
After=docker.service
Description=Docker compose

[Service]
ExecStart=docker-compose up -d

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

More information for this is available in [this post](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6).

Comment: Thanks Chris, I added more information following your comment

Comment: Can you see anything in any logs? Perhaps the docker or syslog?

Comment: I can do `docker container_id logs` for a specific container but that does not give me really useful information

Comment: No, I tried to modify the docker_boot.service but no change. I actually do not know which command is correct between `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d` and `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose up -d` and `ExecStart=docker-compose up -d`